# Is it possible to run from Qt GUI application another GUI process modally?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to run from Qt GUI application another GUI process which will act as modal dialog?

Comment: Process in not a dialog. Process is a process. You can't say "modal process". A process can create gui window(s) or be a service. What exactly do you want to achieve? Start a process and wait for it to finish? or what?

Comment: I know what is a process and what is a dialog. I just want to invoke text editor from my application and I want my gui to be in inactive state while text editor is running. QProcess::waitForFinished is not working becouse events are still collecting and they are getting processed after editor is closed.

Comment: Great. So why don't you describe what you have already done and what problem you have had in the question? An example will also quicken a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could disable your main window widget while you wait to "join" the spawned process.

Comment: My gui is a dialog and I want to invoke an external text editor (GVIM) by clicking button.

Comment: OK I will try disabling. I think it will help.